# Count by group with condition (in R data.table)

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a dataset that consists of `ID` and `Val`.

```
# dataset
ID Val Counter
 1   2       1
 1   4       2
 1  NA       2
 1  13       3
 1  12       4
 2  NA       0
 2  33       1
 2   5       2
 2   5       3
```

A counter per subgroup can be added by `dt[, normal_counter := 1:.N, by=ID]`. I am looking for a counter that is not incremented when there is an `NA`value (see `counter` in example above).

Comment: `dt[!(is.na(Val)), normal_counter := 1:.N, by = ID]`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a cumulative sum of non-`NA` values by group, so:

```
dat[, cntr := cumsum(!is.na(Val)), by=ID]
dat
#   ID Val Counter cntr
#1:  1   2       1    1
#2:  1   4       2    2
#3:  1  NA       2    2
#4:  1  13       3    3
#5:  1  12       4    4
#6:  2  NA       0    0
#7:  2  33       1    1
#8:  2   5       2    2
#9:  2   5       3    3
```